# Null Calculation With SQL Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have Following Table

```
Input           Output
---------------------------------
12.22           
                2.22
```

If I pass Following Sql Statement:

**Select Input,Output,Balance=sum(Input - Output) from Stock group by input,output**

So The Output is:

```
Input            Output       Balance
--------------------------------------
12.22            NULL         NULL
NULL             2.22         NULL
```

If I wants The Output Like Below:

```
Input            Output       Balance
--------------------------------------
12.22                         12.22
                 2.22         10.00
```

Than What is SQL Transact Statement?

**My Table Structure is as Below:**

```
companyID   int
transID     int    -- Primary Key (Auto Increment)
Date        datetime
particulars varchar
input       decimal
output      decimal
```

Note:- I have applied here **Group By** function on **input and Output** columns which doesn't make diference as there is transID columns which is autoincrement hence it should be display all the rows of the table.

Comment: Looks like you want a running totals calculation? If so what are you ordering by? (The `NULL` bit is easy - just use `COALESCE`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may work for you. First, here is how I defined my test table and test data:

```
declare @stock table (
  transId int not null identity(1,1), 
  [date] date not null, -- use datetime if not using SQL Server 2008
  input decimal(7,2) null, 
  [output] decimal(7,2) null
);

insert into @stock values
('1/23/2011', 12.22, null),
('1/23/2011', null, 2.22),
('1/24/2011', 16, null),
('1/24/2011', 3.76, null),
('1/24/2011', null, 5.50);
```

And here is the select I used to produce the results you specified in your question.  The query produces a total for all transactions in transaction ID order for a given day. If you want to calculate the total for multiple days, then comment-out the `AND b.[date] = a.[date]` line.

```
select 
  [date],
  input = isnull(input,0), 
  [output] = isnull([output],0),
  balance = (isnull(input,0)-isnull([output],0)) +
        isnull((
          select 
            sum((isnull(input,0)-isnull([output],0)))
          from @stock b
          where b.transId < a.transId
          and b.[date] = a.[date] -- comment this for totals over multiple dates
        ),0)
from @stock a
order by transId;
```

This query gives:

```
date        input   output  balance
2011-01-23  12.22   0.00    12.22
2011-01-23   0.00   2.22    10.00
2011-01-24  16.00   0.00    16.00
2011-01-24   3.76   0.00    19.76
2011-01-24   0.00   5.50    14.26
```

As a footnote, since the running total value will always be the same for each transaction, I would recommend adding a balance column to your table and calculating the value of the balance column upon insertion of the transaction row. In that way, you would only have to look at the balance of the last transaction to determine what the balance for the transaction being inserted should be.

Answer (score 4):

```
Select Input,
       Output,
       @runbal:=@runbal+SUM(COALESCE(Input, 0) - COALESCE(Output, 0)) AS Balance
from (select @runbal:=0) rt,Stock 
group by Input,Output
```

Comment: It's unlikely that grouping on `Input,Output` is correct, he probably wants to retain the transaction date ordering.  I'd upvote this if you omit the sum and group by.

Comment: @Martin, Here is require @runbal variable but if we create bal1 extra columns for store the rest of calculation and than after divide input and ouput. is it possible?

Comment: @Andomar - I agree this query seems to have no practical application but the OP needs to clarify this @mahesh Can you expand your question to tell us your actual table schema and add a greater amount of sample data and desired results? This gives you your desired results but they don't seem to make much sense and now you seem to be changing them anyway!

Comment: @Martin, I have tested your code but it's simply demand "@runbal" Variable even though you declared it.

Comment: @mahesh - Can you confirm that you are actually on `MySQL` as per the tags? Not Microsoft SQL Server as I see you mention Transact SQL?

Comment: @Martin, I am using sql-2000 and the your code tested on sql query analyzer

Comment: @mahesh - Well in that case you should have tagged it `sql-server`. `mysql` is an entirely different RDBMS! If you edit your question with table schema etc as requested above I'll take a look.

Comment: @Martin, Your code is also works but it's not for sql-2000 server thanks for co-operation.

Answer (score 2):

Any 'normal' operation involving a null yields null.

Read about [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce); use the fact that `COALESCE(foo, 0)` returns `foo` if it is not null and returns 0 if `foo` is null.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Sql-2000 server Solution i wants to share with community which is near by **arcain's Solution**:

Here I Use **Coalesce**  Function instead of **ISNULL**

```
select
transID,
input,
output,
runningtotal =  coalesce(input,0)- coalesce(output,0) +
coalesce(
(select
sum(coalesce(input,0)-coalesce(output,0))
from stock b
where b.transID < a.transID
),0)
from stock a
order by transID
```

Thanks.......

Answer (score 0):

Using *arcain* sample table you can use following query that take advantage of window functioning to get the job done.

```
--arcain sample table 

declare @stock table (
      transId int not null identity(1,1), 
      [date] date not null, -- use datetime if not using SQL Server 2008
      input decimal(7,2) null, 
      [output] decimal(7,2) null
    );

insert into @stock values
('1/23/2011', 12.22, null),
('1/23/2011', null, 2.22),
('1/24/2011', 16, null),
('1/24/2011', 3.76, null),
('1/24/2011', null, 5.50);
```

Query

```
SELECT *,
        SUM( COALESCE(input,0) - COALESCE(output,0) ) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY date,transId ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM @stock
```